# Get an index array from where using Linq - C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array of Vector3's from the polygon collider. I want to have an array of the indexes of all the Vector3's that are higher then a certain y.

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        polygonCollider2D = GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
        float lowestY = polygonCollider2D.points.Min(x => x.y);
// So in the sentence below I want  to have a array of indexes instead of a array of vector3's.
        topPoints = polygonCollider2D.points.Where(x => x.y > lowestY).ToArray();
    }
```

Can I do this with Linq?

Comment: Take a look at the overload for [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that includes the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
indexesOfTopPoints = polygonCollider2D.points.Select((x, index) => index)
.Where(x => polygonCollider2D.points[x].y > lowestY).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use an overload of [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that includes the index like so

```
var topPointIndexes = polygonCollider2D.points
    .Select((p,i) => new{Point=p, Index=i})
    .Where(x => x.Point.y > lowestY)
    .Select(x => x.Index)
    .ToArray();
```

Another option is to just create the set of indexes up front

```
var points = polygonCollider2D.points;
var topPointIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, points.Count())
    .Where(i => points[i].y > lowestY)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Select` allows you to capture the index.

You can first select indexes and filter with the `-1` 'filter sentinel' value I used below,

```
topPointsIndexes = polygonCollider2D.points
    .Select((x, index) => (x.y > lowestY) ? index : -1) 
    .Where(i => i >= 0)
    .ToArray();
```

(or first expand the point and index together, and then filter, as juharr did in his answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
topPoints = polygonCollider2D.points.Select((x, i) => new {obj = x, i = i}).Where(x => x.y > lowestY).Select(x => x.i).ToArray();
```